# Using Argument principle to find roots of complex polynomial. Studying for qualifying exam

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I know we need to use the argument principle to solve this, but I don't know how to use this.

Argument Principle states: $$
\text{number of zeros}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz.
$$
Here
$$
\partial\Omega=\{z=iy, -R\leq y\leq R\}\cup\{ z=Re^{i\theta},-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\}.
$$
It claims that
$$
\int_{-iR}^{iR}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=0.
$$

**I need to find the number of zeros in the first quadrant.** This is a problem for my qualifying exam practice. I found it in Nakhle's complex analysis for applications, and I am not understanding how to apply this theorem. Any ideas on how to proceed or solve this would be greatly appreciated.

The function is $$ f(z) = z^5 + z^4 + 4z^3 + 10z^2 + 9$$

Comment: I encourage you to look up the precise statement of the argument principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle). Then you just need to do a contour integral on the first quadrant with an integrand $f'/f$.